# Rendered more hooks than during the previous render error on component with no conditional hook usage

Tags: reactjs, typescript, apollo-client

I have the following component that renders a clickable link to a file upload

```
import { gql, useLazyQuery, useMutation } from '@apollo/client';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import type FileUpload from '@app/data/models/FileUpload';
import { ExternalLink } from '@app/mcui/components/atoms/business-process/shared/ExternalLink';
import { isNonEmptyString } from '@divvy-homes/utils';

export type Props = {
  uploadId: FileUpload['id'];
};

const FILE_UPLOAD_QUERY = gql`
  query ($id: UUID!) {
    getFileUpload(id: $id) {
      id
      fileName
      url
    }
  }
`;

const SIGN_FILE_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation ($url: String!) {
    signAdminUploadUrl(url: $url)
  }
`;
export const FileUploadLink = ({ uploadId }: Props) => {
  const [fileUrl, setFileUrl] = useState<string>();
  const [fileName, setFileName] = useState<string>();
  const [getFileData] = useLazyQuery<{
    getFileUpload: {
      url: string;
      fileName: string;
    };
  }>(FILE_UPLOAD_QUERY, {
    onError: console.error,
    onCompleted: (data) => {
      setFileName(data.getFileUpload.fileName);
      setFileUrl(data.getFileUpload.url);
    },
    variables: {
      id: uploadId,
    },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    void getFileData({ variables: { uploadId } });
  }, [getFileData, uploadId]);

  const [createSignedDocumentUrl] = useMutation<{ signAdminUploadUrl: string }>(
    SIGN_FILE_MUTATION,
    {
      onError: console.error,
      onCompleted: (urlData) => {
        const signedUrl = urlData.signAdminUploadUrl;
        window.open(signedUrl, '_blank', 'noreferrer');
      },
    },
  );

  return isNonEmptyString(fileUrl) ? (
    <ExternalLink
      onClick={() => void createSignedDocumentUrl({ variables: { url: fileUrl } })}
      text={fileName ?? ''}
    />
  ) : undefined;
};
```

Every time I upload a file using this component, i get a react error `Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.`. React says there was the following change in the order of hooks

```
client.js:1 Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by BusinessProcessDetails. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks

   Previous render            Next render
   ------------------------------------------------------
 1. useContext                 useContext
 2. useContext                 useContext
 3. useContext                 useContext
 4. useContext                 useContext
 5. useRef                     useRef
 6. undefined                  useState
```

Looking through my code I cannot understand why this error would happen. React says it's the first line of the component calling useState that causes the error but this makes zero sense to me. There is no conditional calling to a react hook that should cause this, and the first line of the component throwing this error does not line up with order of hooks changing.

I'm using react 18.2.0, typescript 4.9.5

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the problem was with how the component was being called. The parent component that rendered `FileUploadLink` looked something like so

```
export const MyComponent = ({ fileUpload }: MyProps) => {
  const values = [
    {
      label: 'MyLabel',
      value: fileUpload ? FileUploadLink({ uploadId: fileUpload }) : undefined,
    },
  ];

  return (
    <>
      {values.map((l, v) => {
        <div>{l}</div>;
        {
          v;
        }
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```

the fix was to wrap the component in a tag, i.e.

```
 const values = [
    {
      label: 'MyLabel',
      value: fileUpload ? <FileUploadLink uploadId={fileUpload} /> : undefined,
    },
  ];
```